# How to change chrome browser keyboard shortcuts (without installing any extensions)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

There are many chrome extensions that allow you to change default keyboard shortcuts (e.g. ctrl+w = close tab).

I want to know if there is any way this can be achieved without using any of the extensions. I just want to use something like chrome://keyboard-settings and change shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no other way..  you have to use the extensions now